Out-of-order frames when using FFmpeg to download DASH stream
I'm trying to use ffmpeg to download a DASH stream. It works OK but it seems like in the output file there are some frames that are out-of-order (e.g. for some frames the pts value is lower than the frame that came before it) and this manifests in video players as either pauses or visual glitches.
For testing purposes I'm just trying to save a 2-minute segment, the command line I'm using looks similar to:
ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -i "https://example.com/path/to/stream/index.mpd" -t 00:02:00 -c copy "test.mp4"
I don't want to introduce quality loss by transcoding the stream, are there either any parameters I can use when downloading the stream to automatically discard anomalous frames, or an ffmpeg command I could use after the download is complete to fix up the file?
I'm going to be using this in a script so it would be useful also to know if there's a way to use ffprobe to check a file for this kind of occurrence (so the script can then pass it to be fixed up, if necessary).

Those out-of-order frames are B-frames. They are normal. Does playback glitch with ffplay?

@Gyan not in the same way as other players but ffplay exhibits a different odd behaviour, it seems like segments of the video and audio get repeated, I can see the time indicator in the terminal window jumping backwards and forwards while it is playing. The ffplay I have used for this test is the one from gyan.dev as I assume that's your version, so it should not be an issue with ffplay.

In the end it just seems like ffmpeg is bad at downloading DASH streams correctly. The only working solution I found so far is to use streamlink to do the DASH stream download and ffmpeg with the -t switch can then be used to create a clip from the stream of the desired length.
